# eclipse project properties

Tags: java, eclipse

I am setting properties for `IResource` (`IProject` to be more specific) through `IResource.setPersistenceProeprty`. In this case property value is saved in `.metadata` folder. That is not so good as property is disconnected from `.project` file.

How can I save project property in `.project` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common solution is to use [project scoped preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_preferences.htm) that are stored *in a file located inside the project* (in *<project>/.settings* folder).

```
ProjectScope ps = new ProjectScope(projectResource);
IEclipsePreferences prefs = ps.getNode("my.plugin.id");
prefs.put("key", "value");
prefs.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse .project content is exposed through IProjectDescription interface.

```
IProjectDescription description = IProject.getDescription()
```

Please read:-

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProject.html

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProjectDescription.html