# Eclipse Persistent Properties

Tags: eclipse, properties, include, persistent

In my plugin I have a property page which stores user's include directory paths. I need to store this includes Strings list in disk in shutdown, and reload it when eclipse restarted.

SetPersistentProperty/GetPersistentProperty feature has a limitation of 2 KB, So I can't use it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Project scoped preferences are probably what you need. See a comparsion with persistent properties [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_store_extra_properties_on_a_resource%3F).
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10408630/794836) demonstrates how to implement this.